# Print a row in data.frame using an element from the row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data.frame:

```
e=data.frame(Equipe = c("Washington","Dallas","Chicago","Los Angeles", "St-Louis", "Detroit", "Montréal", "Boston"),
MJ = c(55,56,57,58,56,57,56,57),
V = c(36,32,30,30,25,25,22,24),
D = c(16,19,21,22,19,21,27,31),
DP = c(3,5,6,6,12,11,7,2),
PTS = c(75,69,66,66,62,61,51,50))
```

and the output is like so:

[image: Data Frame]

How do I print the "Montreal" entire row (not using e[7, ]) ?

Comment: You can use `==` i.e. `e[e$Equipe == "Montréal",`]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so.

The first in base R upon the valuable @akrun comment:

```
e[e$Equipe == "Montréal",]
```

The second with `dplyr` package (needs to be installed - use `install.packages("dplyr")` for this) :

```
library(dplyr) 
e %>% filter(Equipe == "Montréal")
```

The third with `data.table` package (also needs to be installed) :

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(e)
DT[e$Equipe == "Montréal"]
```

The combination of the second and the third with a bit advanced base R:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
e %>%
data.table() %>%
'['(e$Equipe == "Montréal")
```