# call a variable name from a dataframe within a function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I can't figure out a simple problem of how to call a variable name from a dataframe  passed as string( function input).

I have a function defined as:

```
box_lambda = function(Valuename,data1){
  data1[,Valuename]=ifelse(data1[,Valuename]==0,0.000001,data1[,Valuename])
  b= boxcox(get(Valuename) ~ Age.Group+Sex , data = data1)
  lambda <- b$x[which.max(b$y)]
  return(lambda)
}
```

But this doesn't work as I get error:
`Error in eval(f): 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

I tried
`data1[[Valuename]]=ifelse(data1[Valuename]]==0,0.000001,data1[[Valuename]])`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you lost a bracket necessary to address a field:

```
data1[[Valuename]]
```

You can also use a seties of other approaches from [here][1] and from [here][2]. For instance you can use:

```
library(dplyr) 
data %>%
filter(!!as.name(Valuename) == 0)
```

So finally you can use :

```
data1[[Valuename]][data1[[Valuename]]==0] <-0.000001
```

This script will replace 0 with epsilon and leave the other values.
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173690/5043424
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219802/5043424